# TestNG @BeforeClass does not run

Tags: java, testng

I have the following code in my test class:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    System.out.println("SetUp");
}

@Test(groups = {"group1"})
private void test1(){
    System.out.println("test1");
    assertEquals(true, true);
}
```

However the `setUp()` is never called despite having the `@BeforeClass` tag. Why?

Comment: Have you runned the test at the class level or just method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since groups are defined for the tests `@Test(groups = {"group1"})`, you are required to add the `alwaysRun` parameter to the `@BeforeClass` anotation like such:

`@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)`